# Запустить из Windows скрипт на сервере

Tags: php, visual-basic

На сервере лежит скрипт test.php , при запуске из     браузера работает, всё выполняет. Как то же самое, но без браузера? Желательно из VB
Очень благодарен,
Сергей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте GET запрос

```vb
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com/test.php") 'адрес вашего скрипта
```

UPD:

Не знаю, будет ли работать на VB6 (нет возможности проверить), но вот такой скрипт с расширением `.vbs` запускается на windows просто двойным кликом:

```vb
Dim oXMLHTTP
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "https://example.com/test.php", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    WScript.Echo "All done"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Something wrong"
End If
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Talleyran. Но у меня VB6, а это для VB.NET 
Можно ли что-то сделать на VB6?

Comment: @СергейБанцер обновил ответ, надеюсь это поможет

Comment: Talleyran  - всё заработало!!! Вы мне очень помогли. Спасибо!